# How should this sentence be constructed?

Tags: grammar

I know that

> I fully understand your feelings.

is correct but I wondered why we cannot use

> I am fully understand your feelings.

Comment: It helps to take out adverbs to check your sentence is grammatically correct.  Adverbs should not change the grammar (only the meaning). Then you get “I am fully understand”, which should sound wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The word *be* (of which *am* is the first person singular) in this sentence either requires an adjective (*I am **hungry***), or a continuous form (*I am **running***). So if you're using *am*, the correct form would be *understanding*. However, that does sound a bit weird as *understanding* is not normally a continuous process that ends at some point (like *running*): you either understand something, or you don't. So that's why the first sentence is correct.

One use where you do have the continuous is the conditional: *If I'm understanding you correctly, ...*, as here you might find that you didn't actually understand. But even here the simmple form sounds better (*If I understand you correctly, ...*)